# Code works in HTML page but not in a Wordpress post

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

First of all, here's the code im using.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="carousel">
<ul>
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/umbrella_trials.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="The Umbrella Trails" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/eiBEvtNNSxg?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">The Umbrella Trails</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/stagnant_day.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="Stagnant Day" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/x3r5vblNAtw?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">Stagnant Day</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/job3a_trailer2.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="Job3(a) Trailer #2" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/setjOKfzNHY?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">Job3(a) Trailer #2</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/job3a_trailer3.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="Job3(a) Trailer #3" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ijkEfmMNr5Q?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">Job3(a) Trailer #3</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/TNaTFiTC.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="Fables from the Mersey - 'The Ninja and The Fella in the Cellar'" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/OdFCo1MmgTI?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">"The Ninja and The Fella in the Cellar"</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/job3a_trailer1.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="Job3(a) Trailer #1" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/3pQUX6VkPTQ?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">"Job3(a) Trailer #1"</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/opening_credits.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="Opening Credits for &quot;It's Liverpool&quot;" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/6a19T8syH60?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">"Opening Credits for "It's Liverpool""</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/1-24.jpg" alt="" /><a class="video" title="It's Liverpool 1-24" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/7r9N-dq1KEE?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">"It's Liverpool 1-24"</a></li>
</ul>
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<a id="prev" class="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
<a id="next" class="next" href="#">&gt;</a>
<div id="pager" class="pager"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="line1"></div>
<div class="paraWrapper">
<div class="span3">
<h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.

<a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>

</div>
<div class="span3">
<h2 class="heading">Heading</h2>
Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.

<a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>

</div>
<div class="social_icons span2"><a class="btn" href="#">
<em class="icon-twitter-sign icon-large"></em> Follow us on Twitter</a><a class="btn" href="#">
<em class="icon-facebook-sign icon-large"></em> Find us on Facebook</a>

<a class="btn" href="#">
<em class="icon-facetime-video icon-large"></em> Subscribe on Youtube</a>

</div>
</div>
<div id="line2"></div>
```

If I paste the into a simple HTML page (taking out the spefic php code) it works fine (Along with the required Javascripts).

If I paste it into a Wordpress theme im trying to build from it however. It wont work..

I even tried pasting the code directly into my `page.php` file and while it does work. It's not what I want as it needs to have it's content accessed easily.

I'wordpresve tried installing the Raw-HTML add-on and it makes no difference.

I'm using the latest vesion of Wordpress (3.3.1)

Answer (score 1):

You are using php in your code. Wordpress must be cleaning your post by removing the php for security reasons. I dont think you can put php in your post. You would need to modify your wordpress to support php in the post but that wont be easy

Comment: im using the exec-php add-on that allows me to put php code in my posts  (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/)

Comment: make sure its compatible with your version of wordpress

Comment: also try to replace "bloginfo('template_directory')" with something like "echo 'testing'" and see if it outputs that. If it outputs that, then it means php is working, and the problem is with the function being called.

Answer (score 1):

You couldtry to use Shortcode to switch the  by a shortcode that will write the absolute /path/ to the Template folder?